# Can I collect restitution for stolen goods if my insurance has replaced them?

Tags: insurance, theft, restitution

My residence was broken into and burglarized. My renter's insurance covered the cost of the stolen goods, though I did spend time reacquiring the goods and the claim affected my insurance plan was affected as a result.

Is it possible to collect restitution for damages, including goods, time lost, and claims? This is in California.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your insurance policy. Any restitution would normally go to the insurance company.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean any restitution I collect will afterward be collected by the insurance company?

Comment: Probably. The idea of insurance is that they compensate you for your loss. If the loss is reduced, so is the net compensation. Policies here in the UK generally have a clause under which you hand the right to pursue the matter over to the insurance company as part of the condition for making a claim. Like I say, read your policy.